# Can I execute a Doctrine function that delete in database on leaving the page?

Tags: javascript, doctrine, onbeforeunload

I have a project using Symfony, Doctrine and Javascript.
Briefly it's about a planning app and i'm working on the modification page.
So we have the html with some Twig, the controller in php and the javascript file.

The general idea is when a user goes on modification page, it writes it in the database so that 2 users can't modify the same day simultaneously. The thing is I want to delete the row in the database when the user is leaving the page or even closing his navigator suddenly, to let other users modify after him.
I have this in php :

```php
public function modificationDeleteTest(){
        $modificationRepository = new ModificationRepository($this->getDoctrine());
        $modifications = $modificationRepository->findAll();

        // I'm using GET and POST just to be sure to get the date somehow
        if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
            $dateModified = $_GET["date"];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
            $dateModified = $_GET["date"];
        }

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($modifications as $modification) {
            $modifArray[] = array(
                'dateModified' => ($modification->getDatemodified()->format('Y-m-d'))
            );
            
            if($modifArray[$i]['dateModified']==$dateModified){
                $this->modificationDelete($modificationRepository, $modification);
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

And I tried using the window events onunload and onbeforeunload in JS with some Ajax, and maybe 20 different ways :

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if(isset($_GET("date"))){
    dateModified = $_GET("date");
  }
  if (isset($_GET("id"))) {
    idUser = $_GET("id");
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "/ModificationDeleteTest",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {date:dateModified, id:idUser},
    async:false, // so browser waits till xhr completed
    success:function() {
      alert("bye!");
    }
  });
};
```

I'm using routes, I tried with these one :

```
ModificationDeleteTest:
  path: /ModificationPlanning
  controller: App\Controller\ModificationPlanningController::modificationDeleteTest
  methods: [POST]
```

Unfortunately it seems that the php functions are never called
I also tried to call them outside of the class but because of Doctrine and $this, it doesn't work either.
It's been a full day that I'm just cycling between errors and functions not called, so I'm asking you for some advice

PS : Note that I'm beginning with Doctrine, JS and especially Ajax, that's why I have a hard time to use them combined